# How to share common css and other resources among grails projects?

Tags: css, grails, sharing

I'm working on a grails-based web application that will be composed of a couple of different grails projects, each developed by a separate team, which will eventually all be unified under a common "portal."   So they need to have the same look and feel, at least to some degree.

Is there a "blessed" way to share resources like this among projects?  Something using the grails plugin architecture maybe?  Would it make sense to just create a separate lightweight project containing nothing but the css and any shared resources?  How have the rest of you handled sharing things between different grails projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use a plugin.

Let your self be inspired from the jQuery plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/jquery

Comment: This idea makes sense.  What's the best way to reference resources inside an installed plugin?  The only way I've got so far is to write a custom taglib.  Is there a more "direct" way, something like

<g:link rel="stylesheet" url="${resource(dir:'css', file:'mycss.css', plugin:'myplugin')}"/>

Answer (score 2):

For those who googled this answer and interested how to share Domain models and other stuff it is very good example [here](http://www.nslms.com/2010/03/10/modularizing-your-grails-application-domain-classes/).